# Swift AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions error

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, uiapplication

Here is my code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

I am reading through tutorials for `local push notifications` for my `iOS` app and this function comes up a lot however when implementing it in my project I get this error:

> *Invalid redeclaration of 'application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)'*

My question is why am I getting this error and what is the correct function to replace it with?

I read the documentation in `Xcode` and it is telling that is function exists which is why I am confused.

Comment: I guess you mention this function two times with different parameters. This function should be only one time to call in Appdelegate. Thats it.

Comment: Yeah I seemed to have missed it in my AppDelegate, thanks for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need not to declare this function it is available out of the box in your app delegate file. In app delegate this is the first function available Use it to put your logic.

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't see it there, the AppDelegate file is overwhelming and I thought I checked to make sure it wasn't there but it turns out it is. Thanks

Comment: Glad I could be of help.